# Jenkin's job doesn't save the parameters from the Build Envirnoment section

Tags: jenkins

When I create a new job in Jenkins, I mark some items from the "Build Environment" section and I save the changes. The next time that I open the job, the information saved from these items is missing.

I tried to delete the last plugins installed in Jenkins but the problem is still there.

[image]

Anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue.
Jenkins version `2.277.2-lts-alpine (docker)`
Browser was throwing such error:

```
TypeError: $(...).next is not a function    behavior.js:119
    at applyNameRefHelper (hudson-behavior.js:1544)
    at applyNameRefHelper (hudson-behavior.js:1549)
    at applyNameRef (hudson-behavior.js:1538)
    at hudson-behavior.js:1201
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at behavior.js:116
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at behavior.js:111
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.applySubtree (behavior.js:93)
(anonymous) @   behavior.js:119
(anonymous) @   behavior.js:111
applySubtree    @   behavior.js:93
apply   @   behavior.js:76
(anonymous) @   behavior.js:71
window.onload   @   behavior.js:133
window.onload   @   behavior.js:133
load (async)        
addLoadEvent    @   behavior.js:132
createSearchBox @   hudson-behavior.js:2472
(anonymous) @   configure:7
```

In my case one of the plugin was messing up the jenkins job configuration page and it was `Team Foundation Server Plug-in`. I just disabled it and then I could save changes in Build Envirnoment section without any issues.
I was able to find broken plugin by chrome developer tools.

I hope this could help you guys, regards.